# How Do I Make My AWS S3 Bucket Private and Give Objects Read Access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 buckets that are identified as Public. All but one was created in 2017. The other one was created in 2019. When I created them I didn't do anything special regarding access to the bucket. I made the assumption that by default I would have to give access to the bucket after reading this paragraph.

***By default, Amazon S3 blocks public access to your account and buckets. If you want to use a bucket to host a static website, you can use these steps to edit your block public access settings.***

I was apparently wrong. This morning I received an email stating that they highly suggested that I change my bucket policy because my buckets were public. I read the documentation that they provided but I was unsuccessful in finding how to make my bucket private but allow get access to the objects.

The only options at the account and bucket levels include actions on both objects and buckets.

- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access
  control lists (ACLs)
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access
  point policies
- Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies

I tried several of them but I couldn't access any of the objects on my website.

The only entry in my access control list for each bucket is for the bucket owner which has all access.

I want to modify my bucket policy which only includes the GetObject access. This code is based on the AWS S3 documentation.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nbcbigbend/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have done web searches but all the solutions I have found has made the assumption that the bucket by default is private and people wanting to make it public. I have not made any bucket changes after creating them years ago but now they have been identified as Public. It appears something has changed with how new buckets are created since I created my last one in 2019.

I want to add something to my JSON code to make my buckets private or at least restrict access to the owner. So far I haven't found out how to do that.

Comment: To whom you want to give read access to? above policy is giving read access to everyone on the internet.

Comment: I want to make my Public S3 bucket private by changing the bucket policy I posted which I know gives read access to object to everyone. The buckets have website data.

Comment: if you have static website data and you want this bucket data exposed from web, the policy you have is exactly what we need . [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html#bucket-policy-static-site) is the document. Other option we have is setting up cloudfront and allow access to S3 only from cloudfront.

Comment: I just read that my bucket is considered public because I am giving an access to everyone, in this case GetObject access. I'm not doing anything else since the documentation says that the default of buckets is private.

Comment: To make this bucket private and restrict access to IAM principals who have permission to access the bucket, simply delete the bucket policy. That reverts to the default behavior (private).